# Drawing upon 'pixel's path' from .xml file (C#)

Tags: c#, html, winforms, graphics, system.drawing

everyone!

I’m developing an application, which will be used to analysed camera’s footage from fire tower’s.
**I’m completely new with programming.**

What I’m trying to accomplish:

When a camera’s footage is loaded in pictureBox, I have to be able to drawn on the photo. 
What’s important – the issue is not free-hand drawing. I can do that.

**A problem, for me, is drawing upon particular path dilimited by pixels from .xml file.**

The .xml file is in the same folder as camera’s footage.

Is there any way, to loading „pixel’s patch” from .xml file along with camera’s footage loaded?
In such circumstances,  drawing area will be limited to sequence of pixels, from .xml file.

Any comments, suggestions from you will be very welcome.
I’m not expecting  complete code. Just helpful advice.

Example of .xml file:

```
    <SequenceInfo HasSmoke="" Azimuth="154.2" Inclination="682" Zoom="10329" TowerName="Makoszka" Time="2015-02-20 11:02:59">
  <Horizon>382,377,377,380,378,374,374,374,375,374,374,375,376,375,374,373,373,376,377,377,376,378,376,377,378,374,378,378,378,377,376,374,376,376,378,376,373,373,376,377,379,378,376,377,376,377,374,379,378,375,379,374,376,373,373,371,375,372,372,371,375,373,371,373,371,373,370,372,373,373,371,370,371,375,377,372,371,370,372,370,370,369,371,380,369,372,371,373,369,372,368,370,369,368,368,367,369,367,367,368,368,367,375,366,368,368,366,370,368,365,369,366,369,365,367,372,368,367,368,370,369,366,366,369,367,366,365,364,366,365,365,365,368,368,366,365,366,366,365,366,366,366,369,365,366,364,364,364,364,364,364,369,366,364,369,366,366,364,368,367,372,363,363,363,369,369,369,367,363,369,365,364,363,363,363,364,365,363,361,363,363,364,365,366,369,366,366,369,369,366,366,371</Horizon>
</SequenceInfo>
```

My English isn’t perfect, so I added graphic, what I intend to get.

[image]

**Additional information:**

The first X value starts from 0 and progressively increase (1,2... n etc.) with each Y value from .xml file.

I would also like to add, that for each camera’s footage sequence is a separate .xml file (one sequence = one .xml file and one sequence = the same area).
So, in one folder, there’re a unique camera’s footage sequence and one .xml file. Each .xml file has the same title ‘info’.

I want to be able to drawing line by clicking the mouse button, not through code. But the line should be limited by X,Y values. Maybe that sounds a little crazy, but it’s important to me ;).
I think, that four pixel's could work.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Well, you'll need to explain what the data in `<Horizon>` is referring to. Do those values represent the Y positions of the pixels? Something else?

Comment: Yes. The values given from .xml file are represents Y positions of the pixels. 

_<Horizon>_ is a line running across the horizon (the skyline?). 

For example, If camera’s footage shows forest, Y values divide photography between forest and sky.

Comment: Yes, ok, and then? The X part? Is it something like: the first value means `Point(0, 382)`, the second is `Point(1, 377)` and so on? A good description of the problem is half of the solution (not sure about the percentage, actually :) Do you need to paint this stripe/line yourself (dragging the mouse pointer) or the code should do it? The stripe/line height, what should it be? 1 Pixel, more?

Comment: [1]
I'm sorry for the late response.

I'll write it down more specifically. Or... at least I do my best ;).

The first X value starts from 0 and progressively increase (1,2... n etc.) with each Y value from .xml file.

Comment: [2]
I would also like to add, that for each camera’s footage sequence is a separate .xml file (one sequence = one .xml file and one sequence = the same area).

Comment: [3]
So, in one folder, there’re a unique camera’s footage sequence and one .xml file. Each .xml file has the same title ‘info’.

Comment: [4]
I want to be able to drawing line by clicking the mouse button, not through code. But the line should be limited by X,Y values. Maybe that sounds a little crazy, but it’s important to me ;).

Comment: [5]
I think, that four pixel's could work.
Thank you so much!